# How can admin assign taks to user in yii2

Tags: yii2

[image]In our website, we have roles admin and jr. researcher and sr. researcher. The requirement , Admin can assign task to user. how to achive that is there any widget orsomw code which fulfill the requirement .

want to send checkbox selected company to selected user

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part.

Comment: @Yupik edited question.  didnt found anythings to send between users. thats why  i post this question

Comment: Did you really tried something? We won't write full solution for you, we can fix your code but don't expect that we will do everything for you.

Comment: @Yupik I dont want full solution. just want to know the way to send somethig between user without mail. and also It is not compulsion on you to give answer. Actually I am new to this YII framework . and trying to learn all this things

Answer (score 0):

Writing an entire RBAC application here seems to me too and in any case it would not be the right place so the only advice I can give you is looking for some extension like this RBAC Manager (for me is the best for yii2): [mdmsoft/yii2-admin](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin)

For more info about installation/configuration you can follow this link:

[Yii 2.0: Installation guide: Yii-2 advanced template with RBAC system](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/848/installation-guide-yii-2-advanced-template-with-rbac-system/)

With this module/package you can do a number of very interesting things like assign role to user.

Comment: I already have mdmsoft/yii2-admin. also roles like admin ,junior researcher, senior researcher, manager and so on . I just want to send task or assign task between this roles